# Dynamic require defined not supported by Metro error, when using Sequelize with react-native

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, sequelize.js

I am using the node_module Sequelize in a react-native ios app, the file `data-types.js` located in the node_module/sequelize folder is causing the react-native app build to fail with the error `Dynamic require defined at line 1033; not supported by Metro`

The portion of the code in data-types.js, line 1033:

```
const dialectNames = ['postgres', 'mysql', 'mariadb', 'sqlite', 'mssql'];
const dialectMap = {};
for (const d of dialectNames) {
  dialectMap[d] = require(`./dialects/${d}/data-types`)(DataTypes);//<--Line 1033 
}
```

[image]

Would anyone have a solution to this issue?

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/52

Had to alter the code for it the work:

```
const dialectNames = ['postgres', 'mysql', 'mariadb', 'sqlite', 'mssql'];
const dialectMap = {};
//for (const d of dialectNames) {
//  dialectMap[d] = require(`./dialects/${d}/data-types`)(DataTypes);
//}
dialectMap['postgres'] = require(`./dialects/postgres/data-types`)(DataTypes);
dialectMap['mysql'] = require(`./dialects/mysql/data-types`)(DataTypes);
dialectMap['mariadb'] = require(`./dialects/mariadb/data-types`)(DataTypes);
dialectMap['sqlite'] = require(`./dialects/sqlite/data-types`)(DataTypes);
dialectMap['mssql'] = require(`./dialects/mssql/data-types`)(DataTypes);
```